# Do not allow any extra fields in Flask-restplus models

Tags: python, flask-restful

I am using Flask Rest-plus models to validate a POST payload, however the I want the model to error out if any extra/unknown fields are present.

Model which am using:

```
interface_config = api.model('Network Interface Validation', {
    'gateway': fields.String(required=True, description='Gateway IP'),
    'subnet': fields.String(required=True, description='Subnet IP'),
    'netmask': fields.String(required=True, description='Netmask'),
    'vlan_id': fields.Integer(required=True, description='VLAN ID'),
    'type': fields.String(required=True, description='IP Version')
})
```

I want to error out payload which contains:

```
 {
    "gateway": "172.22.191.129",
    "subnet": "172.22.191.128",
    "netmask": "255.255.255.128",
    "vlan_id": 887,
    "type": "static",
    "extra_key_name": "<some_str>"
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can somehow extract keys from restplus model, let's name it `x`, then extract keys from post payload `y = request.get_json().keys()`. Convert both variables to sets and calculate a difference: `set(y) - set(x)`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend swapping to marshmallow, as docs says: `The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTPlus is slated for removal and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with other packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as marshmallow). This means that it will be maintained until 2.0 but consider it deprecated. Don’t worry, if you have code using that now and wish to continue doing so, it’s not going to go away any time too soon.`

Comment: How do I extract all keys from the restplus model? Just to add some fields can also be "optional" in model, but they may or may not be present in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the `marshal` function in `flask_restplus`, to reuse the model definition, and skip extra fields.

```
from flask_restplus import marshal
marshal(api.payload, schema, skip_none=True)
```